# Iterate through 2 lists of shapes within a single foreach C#

Tags: c#, foreach, office-interop, office-addins

I have 2 lists of shapeIds from 2 seperate PowerPoint presentations, one from and original PowerPoint and another from an edited PowerPoint.

I now want to compare the items in these 2 lists ShapeId's to each other. For example I want to compare the colour and the font size etc.

I've tried a number of ways to do this and decided the best way to would be to iterate through each ShapeId in the 2 lists. Is there anyway I can iterate through each list within one foreach loop? Such as `foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide slide item1 in list1, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide slide item2 in list2)`

My code is as fallows

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout = pptPresentationOriginal.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides Originalslides;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides EditedSlides;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape originalShp;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape editShp;
    Originalslides = pptPresentationOriginal.Slides;
    EditedSlides = pptPresentationEdit.Slides;
    List<char> l = new List<char>();
    List<char> l2 = new List<char>();
    List<int> originalShapesListID = new List<int>();
    List<int> editedShapesListID = new List<int>();
    List<int> originalListID = new List<int>();
    List<int> editedListID = new List<int>();
    List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape> originalList = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape>();
    List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape> editList = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape>();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape editedShpID;
```

Logic

```
    String pps = "";

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide slide in Originalslides)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape originalShape in slide.Shapes)
        {
            originalShp = originalShape;
            if (originalShape.HasTextFrame == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
            {
                var textFrame = originalShape.TextFrame;
                if (textFrame.HasText == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                {
                    var textRange = textFrame.TextRange;
                    pps += originalShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                    foreach (char word in pps)
                    {

                        l.Add(word);
                        Debug.WriteLine(word);
                    }

                }
            }
            originalShapesListID.Add(originalShape.Id);
            originalShapeID = originalShape.Id;
            originalList.Add(originalShape);
        }

        originalListID.Add(slide.SlideID);
    }

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide slide in EditedSlides)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape editShape in slide.Shapes)
        {
            editShp = editShape;
            if (editShape.HasTextFrame == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
            {

                var textFrame = editShape.TextFrame;
                if (textFrame.HasText == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                {
                    var textRange = textFrame.TextRange;
                    pps += editShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                    foreach (char word in pps)
                    {
                        l.Add(word);
                        Debug.WriteLine(word);
                    }
                }
            }

            editedShapesListID.Add(editShape.Id);
            editedShapeID = editShape.Id;
            editList.Add(editShape);




        }

        editedListID.Add(slide.SlideID);


    }
```

Here is where I want to go through the 2 lists and compare each item (ShapeId) in each list. I want to do something like this.

```
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape editShape in editedShapesListID, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape original in originalShapesListID )
    {

        if (originalShapeID == editedShapeID)
        {


            if (original.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB != editShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB)
            {
                originalShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.StrikeThrough.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about using this?:
`foreach (Shape editShape in editedShapesListID) {
   if(originalShapesListID.containts(editShape) {
     int index = originalShapesListID.FindIndex(a => a.Prop == oProp);
     Shape originalShp = originalShapesListID.get(index);
     if(originalShp.RGB != editShape.RGB) {
       originalShp.StrikeThrough.ToString();
     }
   }
}`

Comment: If you are sure that the no. of items in both the objects are always same, then you can use "traditional" for loop. The loop index can be used to refer objects in both the lists in your if statement.

Comment: @Thangadurai I'm not gangrened that both lists will be the same length. Could you post a small example of what this for loop would look like. Thanks

Comment: @Thangadurai something like this?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < originalList.Count; i++)
            {
                var o = originalList[i];
                var ed = editList[i];
                if (o.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB != ed.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB)
                {
                    o.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.StrikeThrough.ToString();
                }
            }`

Comment: @CraigGallagher, Yes exactly.

Comment: @Thangadurai what if my 2 lists have a different count? How would that work?

Comment: When they have a different size my way could work since I use FindIndex to determine the index and then get the object. I just made a mistake and oProp has to be replaced with editShape.

Comment: @CraigGallagher, I am not very sure about the kind of data that you are dealing with. But if it does not exist in the "originalList" then there is no way that you can edit it right?

Comment: @Thangadurai basically I have 2 powerpoints. Shapes can be edited in the edit PowerPoint and shapes can be deleted which would throw off the count of the originalList list as it would now have more shapes than the editList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to match the items on a specific key `Id`. A good option would be to use a `join`. Join will build a hash-table for the inner collection which has O(1) lookup.

```
var q = from original in originalShapes
        join editedTmp in editedShapes on original.Id equals editedTmp.Id into g
        from edited in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
           original,
           edited
        };

foreach(var item in q)
{
    //item.edited might be null if no matching original was found.
    if (item.edited == null || item.original.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB != item.edited.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB)
    {
       item.original.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.StrikeThrough.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `foreach(var item in q)` doesn't seem to loop through each shape. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: It will loop all the shapes that have a matching editedShape. If you want non matched shapes also you have to change it into a left join. Let me know if you need help writing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var originalEnumerator = originalShapesListID.GetEnumerator())
  foreach (var editShape in editedShapesListID)
  {
    if (!originalEnumerator.MoveNext()) break;
    var original = originalEnumerator.Current;

    ...
  }
```

Comment: Just because you expanded `foreach` to `GetEnumerator/MoveNext` doesn't mean you aren't looping twice. It's still the same problem, just harder to read

Comment: If I wanted simply to expand one of the `foreach`es, its `MoveNext` would have been outside the other foreach.

Comment: Are you trying to emulate `Enumerable.Zip` with this code? You should have explained what it does then, or just mentioned `Zip`. The OP isn't asking about `Zip` though

Comment: Zip creates an extra object (third enumerator) on the heap that encapsulates the same pair of enumenators, delegate for selecting the result and a bunch of other fields. I just find it a little excessive for the shire purpose of not using the enumerators explicitly.

Comment: Of course, if the task is to match the elements of two sequences by some key other then the index of elements, then to avoid full search either some additional structure should be created to quickly lookup the elements of one sequence by the key while iterating through another, or the sequences should be sorted by the key. And the question is not put correctly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 Dictionary instead of 4 Lists and then using `Join`.

Here is an example with int and string (replace string  with Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape for your issue):

```
Dictionary<int, string> loDicOriginal = new Dictionary<int, string>();
Dictionary<int, string> loDicEdit = new Dictionary<int, string>();

loDicOriginal.Add(1, "int 1 list 1");
loDicOriginal.Add(2, "int 2 list 1");
loDicOriginal.Add(3, "int 3 list 1");

loDicEdit.Add(1, "int 1 list 2");
loDicEdit.Add(3, "int 3 list 2");

var loQuery = loDicOriginal.Join(loDicEdit, 
    dicOrg => dicOrg.Key, 
    dicEdit => dicEdit.Key, 
    (entryOrg, entryEdit) => new { Original = entryOrg, Edit = entryEdit });

foreach (var loOut in loQuery)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}->{1} | {2}->{3}", loOut.Original.Key, loOut.Original.Value, loOut.Edit.Key, loOut.Edit.Value);
}
```

Output is:

```
1->int 1 list 1 | 1->int 1 list 2
3->int 3 list 1 | 3->int 3 list 2
```

I hope it is clear what I mean.